# Deploying sharing rules to scratch orgs

Tags: sharing, salesforcedx

So basically, we are trying to deploy our project for the first time to a scratch org. We have already solved 99% of the issues when doing a sfdx force:source:push, however, we still are not able to solve the ones related to sharing rules.

As the metadata contains several sharing rules, we receive this error message:

```
The sharing calculation you requested can't be processed right now, because it interferes with another operation already in progress.
```

How are we suposed to push or project to the scratch org if its imposible to push the sharing rules because you can only deploy one at a time?

Thanks all!

Comment: Have you tried pushing to a new scratch org that hasn't been pushed to before no matter if it was successful or not? We push multiple sharing rules to scratch orgs so I know its possible.

Comment: @ZackWalton yes, I'm trying to deploy to a new scratch org. Also seems there is no way to enable deferred sharing calculation in the scratch org, even we have it enabled in production. We just get a lot of messages like this:

"N/A    sharing operation already in progress"

Comment: @MarcM. did you find a solution?  I am running into the same issue.

Comment: More info here https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/268450/62835