# Defer Sharing Calculation - Scratch org issue?

Tags: salesforcedx, sharing, scratch-org, scratch-org-definition-file

I know there is possibility to turn on this feature using Scratch Org config file.

```
{
"orgName": "Scratch1",
"language": "en_US",
"edition": "Enterprise",
"features": ["Entitlements","MultiCurrency", "API", "AuthorApex", "ContactsToMultipleAccounts", "ProcessBuilder", "StateAndCountryPicklist", "DeferSharingCalc"],
"settings": { 
    "orgPreferenceSettings":{  
        "translation": true,
        "chatterEnabled" : true,
        "disableParallelApexTesting" : true,
        "pathAssistantsEnabled" : true,
        "notesReservedPref01" : true
    },  
    "orderSettings": { 
        "enableOrders": true
    }, 
    "accountSettings": {
        "enableAccountTeams": true
    },
    "opportunitySettings": {
        "enableOpportunityTeam": true
    },
    "quoteSettings": {
        "enableQuote": true
    }
}
```

}

issue is this does not work for me and all my new orgs automatically try to recalculate sharing on sfdx push - and it fail.
Was anyone able to create scratch with this function enabled?
I can't see what I am doing wrong...
I will appreciate any help! :)

Comment: Do you see the "Defer Sharing Calculations" in the setup menus after creating a scratch org with *DeferSharingCalc*? I don't

Comment: Hi @DanielBallinger, 

in fact I can see it setup. Issue is both (Sharing and group) calculations are enabled and I don't have any option to disable it...

Comment: I did not tried it yet...
Still it feels like cheap shot and may potentially cause some issues for development (difference in editions etc...).

Anyway, it is not solution but still - something I can try :)

Comment: I think it’s uncool to open a bounty and then not respond to answers. I see no reason why you don’t select my answer as the answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**DeferSharingCalc** is first step to enable Defer Sharing Calculations feature in scratch orgs. For using this feature, User should have **Manage Users** AND **Manage Sharing Calculation Deferral** permissions. Create a permission set with these permissions and assign it to user, then you will be able to use this feature in scratch orgs.

Answer (score 7):

According to Salesforce this is a somewhat cumbersome two way step where using this org feature needs to be accompanied with a second manual step:

> Enabling the Defer Sharing Rule Calculation feature typically requires
>   two steps - contacting Salesforce support and then enabling the
>   feature in the UI
>   (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_sharing_rule_recalculation.htm&type=5).
>   It appears that the scratch feature "DeferSharingRecalc" is helping
>   with the first step but it requires the user to provision the
>   appropriate permission and then Suspend, Resume or Recalculate sharing
>   rules in the UI.

See [github issues](https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/136#issuecomment-510191477)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [sfdx-hardis](https://github.com/hardisgroupcom/sfdx-hardis) command `sfdx hardis:scratch:create`

If it detects `DeferSharingCalc` in sfdx-project.json, it:

- Generates a Permission set and uploads it to the scratch org using mdapi:deploy
- Assigns the scratch org user to this PS
- Suspend the sharing calculation using `sfdx texei:sharingcalc:suspend`
- Performs force:source:push
- Resumes the sharing calculation using `sfdx texei:sharingcalc:resume`

Note: this behavior is also available with UI in [Visual Studio Code SFDX-Hardis extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NicolasVuillamy.vscode-sfdx-hardis) within commands:

- Start a new task
- Create scratch org (or resume)
- Create scratch org (force new)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, the **DeferSharingCalc** feature needs to be followed up with assigning the User the **Manage Sharing Calculation Deferral** permission and then a final step for the sharing rule calculations to be suspended or resumed/recalculated.

But the final step is now a deployable change using the **deferSharingrules** field in **SharingSettings** metadata: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_sharingsettings.htm